# R matrix apply function with

Tags: r

I have following example matrix x.

```
x <- data.frame(c1=c(1,2,3,2,1,3),
                    c2=c(4,5,6,2,3,4),
                    c3=c(7,8,9,7,1,6),
                    c4=c(4,0,9,1,5,0),
                    c5=c(3,8,0,7,3,6),
                    c6=c(2,8,5,0,5,7),
                    row.names = c("r1","r2","r3","r4","r5","r6"))
```

I need to apply function f to each column where cMin is the column minimum and cMax is the column maximum vectors.

```
cMax <- colMaxs(mat)
cMin <- colMins(mat)
```

I am trying to use apply function `apply(mat,2,f)` as shown below but getting warnings and the result is not correct as well.

```
f <- function(x) (x - cMin[])/(cMax - cMin)
```

**warnings:**
Warning messages:

```
1: In x - cMin[] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In (x - cMin[])/(cMax - cMin) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In x - cMin[] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
4: In (x - cMin[])/(cMax - cMin) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Can someone explain how to use the apply function consisting a vector (cMin or cMax)?

Comment: Could you please clarify what it is you need? Do you want to take every data point and calculate `(data point - column min)/(column max - column min)`?

Comment: You are correct. I want to transform every element with the f function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When subtracting a vector from a matrix, the vector is aligned by columns due to the storage mechanism of a matrix and the recycling rule; So you can transpose the `matrix`, do the calculations with `cMin`, `cMax` and then transpose it back:

```
t((t(mat) - cMin)/(cMax - cMin))

#    c1   c2    c3        c4    c5    c6
#r1 0.0 0.50 0.750 0.4444444 0.375 0.250
#r2 0.5 0.75 0.875 0.0000000 1.000 1.000
#r3 1.0 1.00 1.000 1.0000000 0.000 0.625
#r4 0.5 0.00 0.750 0.1111111 0.875 0.000
#r5 0.0 0.25 0.000 0.5555556 0.375 0.625
#r6 1.0 0.50 0.625 0.0000000 0.750 0.875
```

Comment: Damn it man! You are a genius. Could you please explain in short how it works?

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(magrittr)
x <- data.frame(c1=c(1,2,3,2,1,3),
                c2=c(4,5,6,2,3,4),
                c3=c(7,8,9,7,1,6),
                c4=c(4,0,9,1,5,0),
                c5=c(3,8,0,7,3,6),
                c6=c(2,8,5,0,5,7),
                row.names = c("r1","r2","r3","r4","r5","r6"))

cMin <- apply(x, MARGIN = 2, FUN = min)
cMax <- apply(x, MARGIN = 2, FUN = max)

sweep(x, MARGIN = 2, STATS = cMin, FUN = "-") %>%
  sweep(., MARGIN = 2, STATS = (cMax - cMin), FUN = "/")

    c1   c2    c3        c4    c5    c6
r1 0.0 0.50 0.750 0.4444444 0.375 0.250
r2 0.5 0.75 0.875 0.0000000 1.000 1.000
r3 1.0 1.00 1.000 1.0000000 0.000 0.625
r4 0.5 0.00 0.750 0.1111111 0.875 0.000
r5 0.0 0.25 0.000 0.5555556 0.375 0.625
r6 1.0 0.50 0.625 0.0000000 0.750 0.875
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see from the solutions, the aim it so scale each column to range 0 to 1, linearly, with the smallest value mapping to 0 and maximum to 1.

In like one line, without having to calculate `cMin` and `cMax`

```
apply(x, 2, 
      function(each_col) (each_col - min(each_col))/diff(range(each_col)))

# c1   c2    c3        c4    c5    c6
# r1 0.0 0.50 0.750 0.4444444 0.375 0.250
# r2 0.5 0.75 0.875 0.0000000 1.000 1.000
# r3 1.0 1.00 1.000 1.0000000 0.000 0.625
# r4 0.5 0.00 0.750 0.1111111 0.875 0.000
# r5 0.0 0.25 0.000 0.5555556 0.375 0.625
# r6 1.0 0.50 0.625 0.0000000 0.750 0.875
```

Answer (score 1):

We can just replicate the 'cMin' and 'cMax' and do the calculation

```
(mat - cMin[col(mat)])/(cMax[col(mat)] - cMin[col(mat)])
#    c1   c2    c3        c4    c5    c6
#r1 0.0 0.50 0.750 0.4444444 0.375 0.250
#r2 0.5 0.75 0.875 0.0000000 1.000 1.000
#r3 1.0 1.00 1.000 1.0000000 0.000 0.625
#r4 0.5 0.00 0.750 0.1111111 0.875 0.000
#r5 0.0 0.25 0.000 0.5555556 0.375 0.625
#r6 1.0 0.50 0.625 0.0000000 0.750 0.875
```